# The site's security certificate is signed using a weak signature algorithm! can't access any HTTPS's site

Tags: malware, virus

I'm getting this error on any HTTPS page and can't even login here in SuperUser.com if I use chrome.

> You attempted to reach www.facebook.com, but the server presented a
>   certificate signed using a weak signature algorithm. This means that
>   the security credentials the server presented could have been forged
>   and the server may not be the server you expected (you may be
>   communicating with an attacker). You should not proceed, especially if
>   you have never seen this warning before for this site.
>
> When you connect to a secure website, the server hosting that site
>   presents your browser with something called a "certificate" to verify
>   its identity. This certificate contains identity information, such as
>   the address of the website, which is verified by a third party trusted
>   by your computer. By checking that the address in the certificate
>   matches the address of the website, it is possible to verify that you
>   are securely communicating with the website that you intended and not
>   a third party (such as an attacker on your network).
>
> In this case, the server certificate or an intermediate CA certificate
>   presented to your browser has been signed using a weak signature
>   algorithm such as RSA-MD2. Recent research by computer scientists
>   showed that the signature algorithm is weaker than previously believed
>   and the signature algorithm is rarely used by trustworthy websites
>   today. This certificate could have been forged.

So what I did first thing when I get this error is check the time if it is correct and everything seem to be okay about the timing. Second thing what I did is use `MalwareBytes Anti-Malware to see if I'm infected and the result was none.

I did clear the browser cache to the beginning of the time and still not help.

I did clean uninstall Chrome browser and did not help.

So now what I tried to look is where is the problem and I found something very suspesion

I looked at the certification path from Chrome browser of each page that actually have HTTPS and they look very similar

like an example of https://google.com

[image]

And here is from https://facebook.com

[image]

And here is from https://stackoverflow.com

[image]

It doesn't seem right to me when I see most of them is like `*.*.255.255` ips which is unlikely to be correct because as I remember once when I have problem about time is not match I will see the actual name site from facebook including there.

Not only that. Sometime when I'm actually checking up my regular site and my own site some random video ads will appear in a new tab, and I'm sure that my own website never have any kind of those ads and I also have Adblocker installed on my chrome and it also happen on Firefox about the new tab ads.

Any thought what might be the problem?

EDIT:

I've did the scan again and still nothing found.

```
Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (PRO) 1.61.0.1400
www.malwarebytes.org

Database version: v2012.05.06.03

Windows 7 Service Pack 1 x64 NTFS
Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
alihuta2002 :: ALIHUTA2002-PC [administrator]

Protection: Enabled

6/5/2555 10:28:27
mbam-log-2012-05-06 (10-28-27).txt

Scan type: Quick scan
Scan options enabled: Memory | Startup | Registry | File System | Heuristics/Extra | Heuristics/Shuriken | PUP | PUM
Scan options disabled: P2P
Objects scanned: 238483
Time elapsed: 6 minute(s), 15 second(s)

Memory Processes Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Memory Modules Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Registry Keys Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Registry Values Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Registry Data Items Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Folders Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

Files Detected: 0
(No malicious items detected)

(end)
```

UPDATE: This is what happen when I say there is a new tab randomly open even I'm here in this website and I believe http://superuser.com don't have this kind of ads at all and I'm installed Adblocker so how is this come up?

[image]

UPDATE AGAIN:

After I did tried using Microsoft Security Essential and it founds 4 trojan detected and removed, but now after the restart it can't boot to the screen it has blue screen of death without giving me a time to see what is really the error and asking me to do Start up Repair.

This is a startup repair log:

```
Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log
---------------------- 
Last successful boot time: 5/6/2012 2:51:42 PM (GMT) 
Number of repair attempts: 2
Session details
------------------- 
System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0 
Windows director = D:\Windows 
AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1
```

Comment: It definitely looks like something is attempting to man-in-the-middle your https connections - if malicious, in an attempt to harvest passwords.  If not malicious, then perhaps a proxy server is involved. In any case, do not attempt to login to any sites using this machine until you get an answer.

Comment: I'm very confuse now why is this happening, but the most confusion thing for me is that it's only happen to Chrome :(

Comment: I am no chrome user, but have you tried disabling all addons? (if there are any)

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch This is now a new Google Chrome installed [I did clean uninstall] and still happening :(

Comment: The IP addresses end in *.*.255.255 so that they cover the entire range of associated IP addresses.  Malware is definitely hijacking the connection and inserting a fake HTTPS header, so **do not** log into any websites on your computer until this is fixed.  Check any addons for Chrome, check for viruses.  Does this same problem happen with Firefox/Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Breakthrough No it is only happen with Chrome. I've clean uninstall Chrome and reinstall without having any add-ons and still happening.

Comment: @Ali if you can, scan your computer using [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) and [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/mse).  What do you mean when you say "it also happen on Firefox about the new tab ads"?

Comment: @Breakthrough I'm going to check from both program use asked for. For the ads I just update my question new tab come up without even knowing from where.

Comment: @Ali you definitely have malware.  I would change your passwords from another, secure computer as soon as possible.  Scan the computer ASAP, and if nothing is found, you might want to take the HDD out and scan it from another computer.

Comment: @Breakthrough I used Microsoft Security Essentials as you suggested and found 4 trojans detected and now waiting it to reboot will see if that is help.

Comment: You say this only happens in Chrome. What other browsers did you try?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I did tried with FireFox [latest version] Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please also refer to our *main* questions on the topic:

- [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)
- [How to fix a PC that won't boot after a virus/malware scan?](https://superuser.com/questions/98157/how-to-fix-a-pc-that-wont-boot-after-a-virus-malware-scan)

---

It is very likely that your system and/or connection is compromised and someone is intercepting your internet communication.

Searching for `IopFailZeroAccessCreate` on Google only brings up people complaining about computer problems.

I found some good instructions on [2-viruses](http://www.2-viruses.com/how-to-fix-google-results-hijacker-google-redirect-virus-problem) which may or may not relate to this specific issue. The article seems to deal with a different kind of infection, but the same solution should apply.

1. Check your hosts file for malicious entries.
   Hosts file resides on `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Check DNS (Domain Name Server) settings
3. Checking your proxy settings on Internet Explorer
   Chrome also uses these proxy settings!
4. (Optional) Check your proxy settings on Mozilla Firefox
5. Check your IE add-ons
6. Scan for malicious parasites with spyware/antivirus removers
7. (Optional) Repair Winsock 2 settings with [LSPFix](http://www.cexx.org/lspfix.zip)

Comment: The problem now is that after I did use Microsoft Security Essential to scan and it detects 4 trojan and it removes them. Now my computer can't start up after the reboot :(

Comment: @Ali: I would advise you to immediately back up all relevant data from that computer (by using a Linux Live CD) before doing **anything** else. It can be very difficult to recover from an infection.

Comment: Even I'm on Windows 7 I can use Linux Live CD to backup data?

Comment: @Ali: If you use (for example) a Ubuntu CD, you can boot from it directly into a Linux system. This system should be able to read data from your harddrive and copy it to a network location or another (maybe USB) drive.

Comment: I'm going to try that now.